# IOS: round the cournes of a uicollectionViewCell clipin it's contents

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, calayer

I have a collection view with multiple cell styles and sizes I want to round the corners of the cell using this helper function:

```
void roundCornersOfAView(UIView *view, CGFloat radius, BOOL shadow){
    CALayer* layer = [view layer];
    [layer setCornerRadius:radius];
    [layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
//    CALayer* mask = [CALayer layer];
//    [mask setFrame:CGRectMake(layer.frame.origin.x, layer.frame.origin.y, layer.frame.size.width, layer.frame.size.height)];
//    [mask setCornerRadius:radius];
//    [layer setMask:mask];
    if (shadow) {
        [layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
        //[layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
        [layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
        [layer setShadowRadius:1.0];
        [layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    }
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

using it like this in my cell for row at index path:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:... forIndexPath:indexPath];

roundCornersOfAView([cell contentView], 30, YES);
```

The problem is that images on cell are not clipped in the rounded courners, neither labels or any other subviews, it only clips the background color... what is the best way to round courners and clip its content just like the instagram app?

Comment: try to set clipToBounds = YES;

Comment: already tried... seems like clips to bounds is still part of the bounds property which is a squared CGrect... since this is just editing the layer the clipToBounds doesn't work

Comment: try to set the cell color to Clear color, maybe what you see is the cell and not the contentView. let me know how it goes

Comment: still not working...

Comment: have you tried passing cell instead of [cell contentView]?

Comment: did you try my answer?????

Comment: Any chance you added your image views, labels etc. as subviews of your cell, rather than the cell's content view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling it like this:

```
roundCornersOfAView(cell, 30, YES);
```

using the helper function like this:

```
void roundCornersOfAView(UIView *view, CGFloat radius, BOOL shadow){
    CALayer* layer = [view layer];
    [layer setCornerRadius:radius];
    [layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
    if (shadow) {
            [layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [layer setBorderWidth:0.1f];
            [layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
            [layer setShadowRadius:1.5];
            [layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0)];
        }
        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }
```

The problem was that I was sending the content view instead of the cell itself.

Comment: this should be a category, though

Comment: yea a category would be nicer, this solution clips the shadow though :S